# Modifying a python dictionary from user inputted dot notation

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

I'm trying to provide an API like interface in my Django python application that allows someone to input an `id` and then also include key/values with the request as form data.

For example the following field name and values for ticket 111:

```
ticket.subject = Hello World
ticket.group_id = 12345678
ticket.collaborators = [123, 4567, 890]
ticket.custom_fields: [{id: 32656147,value: "something"}]
```

On the backend, I have a corresponding Dict that should match this structure (and i'd do validation). Something like this:

```
ticket: {
    subject: "some subject I want to change",
    group_id: 99999,
    collaborator_ids: [ ],
    custom_fields: [
        {
            id: 32656147,
            value: null
        }
    ]
}
```

1) I'm not sure exactly the best way to parse the dot notation there, and
2) Assuming I am able to parse it, how would I be able to change the values of the Dict to match what was passed in. I'd imagine maybe something like a class with these inputs?

```
class SetDictValueFromUserInput(userDotNotation, userNewValue, originalDict)
    ...

SetDictValueFromUserInput("ticket.subject", "hello world", myDict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest way is probably splitting the string and indexing based on seperation. For example:

```
obj = "ticket.subject".split(".")
actual_obj = eval(obj[0]) # this is risky, they is a way around this if you just use if statements and predifined variables. 
actual_obj[obj[1]] = value
```

To have further indexing where an object like `ticket.subject.name` might work try using a for loop as so.

```
for key in obj[1:-2]: # basically for all the values in between the object name and the defining key
  actual_obj = actual_obj[key] # make the new object based on the value in-between.
actual_obj[obj[-1]] = value
```